# Writing a JPEG file using libjpeg

Tags: pi-3, webcam

On my pi 3, I receive frames via logitech c270 camera using libuvc and I want those frames to be written in individual JPEG files. 
The camera itself compresses the frames in MJPEG format.
I'm stuck at a point where I don't know how to write these frames into a file. 
I'm thinking of using libjpeg for it but the problem is that my data is already compressed.

Comment: While you're using a Pi to run the program, libuvc is non-Pi specific which makes this more of a general programming question. I think you're likely to get better answers on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: FYI this question was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552617/how-to-convert-motion-jpeg-frames-from-ip-camerartp-stream-to-valid-jpg-image) and [here](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/lossless-extracting-of-jpegs-from-an-mjpeg-video).

Comment: thanks but they say they do it using ffmpeg and C# respectively.
Since I already have individual frame, which is already JPEG compressed, I need a C code/library which will write a JPEG file with already JPEG encoded frame.